# How to limit a matrix class to get only 'X' 'O' or '.'

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I have a board class that makes N*N board of chars.

```
class Cell
{ 
public:
    int row; int col;
};


class Board {
private:
    int size;
    char** matrix = nullptr;
   //many other class functions.
char & operator[](const Cell& cellToChange) {
        if (cellToChange.row < size && cellToChange.col < size) {
            return matrix[cellToChange.row][cellToChange.col];
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
        }
    }
```

now when I use in the main this

```
"board1[{1, 4}] = 'X';"
```

It is changing this place in the matrix to 'X' and any other char.

I need to limit this matrix to only 'X' 'O' or '.'

I"m not allowed to chain the main! I may only change the classes.

My goal I can not achieve right not is to make the program print "error" when I"m trying to do

```
"board1[{1, 4}] = 'z'".
```

And I have wasted hours on hours trying to achieve it and I really need your help here.

This is the whole class I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Cell
{ 
public:
    int row; int col;
};


class Board {
private:
    int size;
    char** matrix = nullptr;

public: 

    Board(int sizeToSet) {                       //constructor with size
        size = sizeToSet;

        matrix = new char*[size];                 //creates a matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new char[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {          //makes every cell in matix '.'
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = '.';
            }
        }
    }



    void printSize() {                            //matrix size print
        cout << size << endl;
    }

    ~Board() {                                    //destructor
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            delete[] matrix[i];
        delete[] matrix;
    }

    Board(const Board& other) {                   //copy constructor
        if (this != &other) {
            size = other.size;
            matrix = new char*[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                matrix[i] = new char[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Board(Board&& other) {                   //move constructor
        size = other.size;
        matrix = other.matrix;
        other.matrix = nullptr;
    }



    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Board& boardToPrint) {       //prints matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < boardToPrint.size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < boardToPrint.size; j++) {
                os << boardToPrint.matrix[i][j] << "  ";
            }
            os << endl;
        }
        os << endl;
        return os;
    }


    char & operator[](const Cell& cellToChange) {
        if (cellToChange.row < size && cellToChange.col < size) {
            return matrix[cellToChange.row][cellToChange.col];
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
        }
    }

    void operator=(char charToAdd) {
        if (charToAdd == 'X' || charToAdd == 'O' || charToAdd == '.') {
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {         
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = charToAdd;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
        }
    }

    const Board& operator=(const Board& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            size = other.size;
            matrix = new char*[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                matrix[i] = new char[size];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = other.matrix[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
};
```

and this is the whole main I"m not allowed to change:

```
#include "Board.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Board board1{4};  // Initializes a 4x4 board
    cout << board1 << endl;   /* Shows an empty board:
    ....
    ....
    ....
    ....
    */
    cout << board1[{1,2}] << endl; // .
    board1[{1,1}]='X';
    board1[{1,2}]='O';
    char c = board1[{1,2}]; cout << c << endl; // O
    cout << board1 << endl;  /* Shows the following board:
    ....
    .XO.
    ....
    ....
    */
    // This should raise an exception
    //  "Illegal"
    board1 = '.';     // Fill the entire board with "."
    cout << board1 << endl;  /* Shows an empty board, as above */
    board1 = 'a';        // This should raise exception
    //  "Illegal"
    board1[{0,1}] = 'x';  // This should raise an exception
    //   "Illegal"

    Board board2 = board1;
    board2[{0,0}] = 'X';
    cout << board1 << endl;  /* Shows an empty board, as above */
    cout << board2 << endl;  /* Shows a board with an X at top-left */

    board1 = board2;
    board1[{3,3}] = 'O';
    cout << board2 << endl;  /* Shows a board with an X at top-left */
    cout << board1 << endl;  /* Shows a board with an X at top-left and O at bottom-right */

    cout << "Good bye!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 7):

What you need is another layer of abstraction.  Since you can't control the right hand side of the assignment, you need to control the assignment operator.  To do that, you need a proxy object.  You'll return that object from the `operator[]` and then you do your logic in it's assignment operator.  That would look like

```
class Proxy
{
    char& val;
    Proxy(char& val) : val(val) {}
    Proxy& operator=(char new_val)
    {
        if (new_val == 'X' || new_val == 'O' || new_val == '.')
        {
            val = new_val;
            return *this;
        }
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid Assignment.  Use X, O, or .");
    }
    // allows this class to implicitly convertible to a char
    operator char() { return val; }
};
```

and

```
Proxy operator[](const Cell& cellToChange) {
    if (cellToChange.row < size && cellToChange.col < size) {
        return {matrix[cellToChange.row][cellToChange.col]};
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("invalid index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it works! But It doesn't print my the error. it just not accepting it. any chance you can explain me why?

Comment: @Dima I updated the code to throw an exception if an invalid assignment happens.

Comment: Thanks alot! you finnaly saved me after a lot of hours of trying!