# how to make '=' overloading work on the other side of the '='

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have made this little c++ program as part of my homework. I"m not allowed to change the main.
I managed  to make

```
board1[{1, 1}] = 'X';
```

but now I"m not able to make

```
char c = board1[{1, 2}];
```

I understand it is not working because c is char type and I"m returning "CellValue" to it. But I cann't understand how to make '=' to work the other way and make it return the value as char when i want it to be on the right side of the '='.
the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CellValue {
public:
    char value;

    void operator=(char charToAdd) {
        if (charToAdd == 'X' || charToAdd == 'O' || charToAdd == '.') {
            value = charToAdd;;
        }
        else {
            cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
        }
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CellValue &CellToPrint) {       //prints matrix
        cout << CellToPrint.value << endl;
        os << CellToPrint.value;
        os << endl;
        return os;
    }
};

class Cell
{
public:
    int row; int col;
};


class Board {
private:
    int size;
    CellValue** matrix = nullptr;

public:

    Board(int sizeToSet) {                       //constructor with size
        size = sizeToSet;

        matrix = new CellValue*[size];                 //creates a matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i] = new CellValue[size];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {          //makes every cell in matix '.'
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                matrix[i][j].value = '.';
            }
        }
    }




    ~Board() {                                    //destructor
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            delete[] matrix[i];
        delete[] matrix;
    }





    CellValue& operator[](const Cell& cellToChange) {
        if (cellToChange.row < size && cellToChange.col < size) {
            return { matrix[cellToChange.row][cellToChange.col] };
        }
        else
            cout << "ERROR!" << endl;
    }


};


int main() {
    Board board1{ 4 };  // Initializes a 4x4 board
    board1[{1, 1}] = 'X';
    board1[{1, 2}] = 't';
    cout << board1[{1, 1}] << endl;
    cout << board1[{1, 2}] << endl;
    char c = board1[{1, 2}];


    return 0;
}
```

I"m just starting to program on c++ so I"m now allowed to use something too smart. I would like to get some help from you. Thanks!

Comment: Like I had in [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59214830/4342498), add `operator char() { return val; }` to `CellValue` to make it convertible to a `char`

Comment: While `operator char()` is probably the best way to go, you can just write `char c = board1[{1, 2}].value;`, since `CellValue::value` is `public`. Note however, that in `Board::operator[]` not all paths return a value.

Comment: You answer helped me a lot. My teacher told me I I need to rewrite it because I is for sure not my code and i"m not understand it.
operator char() { return value; } is what i was missing! Thanks!

operator char() it return char everytime doesnt matter what?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but in the stream inserter, do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: what should I do to make the [] function return value when it is "else"?

Comment: @Dima Maybe throw [`std::out_of_range`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/out_of_range/)

Comment: Oh great, another "teaching" environment where they start off with manual memory management

Answer (score 0):

If an instance of your class is the right-hand side of an assignment, and the left-hand is not of the same type, then a user-defined conversion must be provided in order for this to work.

There are two ways this can work with assignment. The first is that the left-hand object can provide an assignment operator or conversion constructor that takes an object of the type of the right-hand side. This is what you have done with `CellValue::operator=()`, but cannot work when the LHS is `char`, as you cannot modify built-in types.

The second way is that the right-hand object provided a conversion operator to the type of the left-hand side (or something else that can be assigned to it). This is done by adding `operator char()` to your `CellValue` class:

```
class CellValue{
public:
  operator char() const{
    return value;
  }
// rest as before
};
```

This can be a `const` member function because it only reads the data.